# Group resulting rows by hour of the day sqllite android

Tags: android, sqlite, time

There are entries in a table containing 2 columns (integerdata, time). Time is stored in TEXT and is of format HH:MM, which is one of the standard format ( according to [sqllite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)). 'integerdata' is some integer. I am looking to obtain row contents grouped by hour of the day, with integerdata as AVG(integerdata) for each hour. Eg rows:

```
(10, 10:01)
(2, 10:25)
(5, 11:01)
(9, 11:25)
```

I wish to have the output like:

```
6, 10:00 
7, 11:00
```

One novice and **horrible** way is to give a query for each hour range(making 24 queries). Something like:

```
SELECT AVG(integerdata) from table WHERE time BETWEEN 'time1' AND 'time2'
//time1 and time2 can vary between 10:00 to 11:00; then 11:00 to 12:00 ...
```

Second way might be to use GROUP BY Clause, but I am not sure how. I googled and also tried to look on some answers on stackoverflow but was of no help. I would really appreciate any contribution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am looking to obtain row contents grouped by hour of the day, with
>   integerdata as AVG(integerdata) for each hour.

Here is my first idea. Since your time is still `TEXT`, you can use [`substr()`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html) function to get only hour from your time column and then you can use this substring in  `GROUP BY` clause.

```
Select AVG(integerdata), SUBSTR(time, 0, 3) as gt from Table group by gt;
```

I assume that your time format is `HH:MM` so in this case `SUBSTR(time, 0, 3)` returns only hours and now you can start grouping by hours.

It returns: `10`, `11`, `12`, ...